# How to escape an input field in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, xss

I have an input field for a search. The value of this field is a request parameter (webservice call).

I want to prevent the cross site scripting in the input field. How is it possible to do this in Angular2 (Typscript). I have to escape the input value. but how?

My html page:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="domain"  [(ngModel)]='domain'> 
   <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addDomain()">Add</button> <br>
</form>
```

my component:

```
addDomain(){
    this._httpService.addDomain(this.domain)
        .subscribe(
            data => data,
            error => console.log(error)
        );
}
```